# AS3 traverse object with property-string

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible in AS3 to traverse an object with a given property-string?

- **data["x"]** (= data.x) -> works
- **data["x.y.z"]** (= data.x.y.z) -> doesn't work

Is there a way to convert **data["x.y.z"]** to **data[x][y][z]**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
var keys = "x.y.z".split(".");
var access_property = function(object, keys) {
    for each (var key in keys) {
        object = object[key];
    }
    return object;
}

var prop = access_prop(data, "x.y.z");
```

I havent tested this and there is no error handling for example if there is no key of the given name.

Comment: Isn't this somehow Javascript? :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This way I can get the nested z property from data. Any suggestions on how to set the z property?